# Node.js Filename invalid encoding characters

Tags: node.js

When writing a new file and the filename contain unicode characters with this code:

`fs.writeFile('êèñéß™.txt', 'hello')`

the filename in the filesystem returns something along the lines like this:

`ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿.txt`

Is there a way to specify the filename encoding?

Comment: Your code is perfectly running in my system. I could save the text in the file    'êèñéß™.txt'.

Comment: Could this be a unix issue?

Comment: Is your js source code file encoded in UTF-8 as well?

Comment: @makkesk8 No,this can't be an unix issue

Comment: @shambalambala yes